# How do I import taxonomy terms

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, search

This is almost 6000 rows of taxonomy terms ranging over 8 columns that i'd like to import from csv. I would like to use it for facet search.

The CSV is located [here](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6324436?visit_id=1-636231288363745146-4175571651&rd=1) (google_product_category).

The format is like:

```
# Google_Product_Taxonomy_Version: 2015-02-19
1 - Animals & Pet Supplies
3237 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Live Animals
2 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies
3 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies
7385 - Animals & Pet Supplies > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Cage Accessories
```

Answer (score 2):

As popular Drupal 7 modules like [Taxonomy CSV import/export](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv) and [Taxonomy Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager) are not ported to Drupal 8, I recommend a very simple but functional module called [term_csv_tree_import](https://github.com/grahl/term_csv_tree_import).

After installing, go to `/csv-tree-import` and paste your taxonomies into the form. It assigns parent values from right to left, empty intermediate elements are allowed. You have to convert your CSV into the following format:

```
"element","subelement","subsubelement"
```

Comment: Noob here, how do you access /csv-tree-import I have installed and activated your module but i cant find where to use the option from admin

Comment: It's your Drupal install directory + the path, for example: http://www.example.com/csv-tree-import

Comment: Ah was expecting /term_csv_tree_import instead of ..../csv-tree-import. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

At the time of this writing, the options on drupal.org are:

- [Taxonomy Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_import)
- [Term CSV Export Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_csv_export_import)
- [Migrate Source CSV](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_source_csv)

I'd evaluate based on the method you're most comfortable with, the issues in the queues and the number of sites using each module.

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer to the following module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/hti

However, CSV file needs to be formatted a bit differently. You would find a sample screenshot there.

Comment: What  does this module do?